# How to centering a form

Tags: html, css, forms, css-float, centering

I have a simple form...

```
<label>name</label><input type="text" id="name">
<label>email address</label><input type="text" id="email">
```

Here is the CSS so far; the input elements line up vertically, as desired.

```
<div>
    <label>name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
</div>
<div>
    <label>email address</label>
    <input type="text" id="email">
</div>

div
{
    padding: 5px;    
}
label
{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/shooter/XpjYJ/1/)

The problem is that I want my form centered on the page. How can I center with floated elements (or alternatively how to align without floating)?

Must work in all browsers, IE6 included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XpjYJ/7/

I placed your html inside a div. I then gave the div a fixed width, and set the margin to `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: `margin: auto` doesn't work properly in older versions of IE I believe?

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet, I believe that's only IE 5.5 or lower. I could be wrong, but I haven't been since the last time :)

Comment: Neither quirksmode (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) nor CanIUse (http://caniuse.com/#agents=ie&eras=farfarpast&cats=CSS) show any issues with margin and IE6.

Comment: @ also if you supporting IE 5.5 or lower (over even 6 in my opinion) than your going to have to rethink your entire stylesheet/markup

Comment: Ok thats fine, I don't need to support lower than IE6. What can I do in the case that my input elements are not fixed width? Dropdowns populated dynamically for example. So I then can't give the container a static width.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet Whilst this does work you are adding more html markup to the document that is unnecessary and unsemantic. If you see my answer below it reduces the markup, increases semantic value as well as centering it.

Comment: @fearofawhackedplanet, you can use a percentage instead of a fixed width.

Comment: @james I was not trying to cause offence only speaking the truth. People are too quick to just add divs to things these days. It is not necessary and makes the code more crowded then it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Use `auto` for the left and right margin on something that encloses your form elements (presumably, the form).

```
form {
    width: 80%;
    border: solid black 1px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Without the width specification, the form will be 100% of the width of its container.  The black border just makes it easy to see what's going on.

[An updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVLrN/).

Answer (score 1):

You can put your form in a centered container.

In this case, the form elements are floated left (or right) and you only need to apply the horizontal positioning on the container.

example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XpjYJ/6/)

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<form>
<label>bla</label>
<input />
...
</form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {margin:0 auto;}
form {width:200px;}
input {float:right;}
```